# ajax with java not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

Hi I am tring my second ajax program with servlet. But its not working. Please help

```
    index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function callServer(str){
alert(str);
var myxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
myxml.onreadystatechange = function  {
    if(myxml.readyState == 4 && myxml.status == 200)
        document.getElementById("replay").innerHTML = myxml.responseText;
}
myxml.open("GET",""/suggest?query=str",true);
myxml.send();

  }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input id="enter" type="text" onkeyup="callServer(this.value)" />
   <div id="replay"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

and my servlet is here...

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  @WebServlet("/suggest")
  public class suggest extends HttpServlet {
public suggest() {
    super();
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {
    String [] values = {"sha","kla","hello","bun"};
    String query = request.getParameter("query");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i].equals(query)) 
            response.getWriter().write("OK its available dude... "+query);
        else response.getWriter().write("Sorry not yet... "+query);

    }

}
```

}

Here I think the error may be in the js function callserver. I have checked each line with an alert stament to check and it worked fine until the line
                         myxml.onreadystatechane = function. the alert worked till there. Pls help

Comment: `function  {`, `""/suggest?query=str"`... You should at least run your code through http://jshint.com or something before posting code with such basic syntax errors.

Comment: Or use the developer tools that come with any browser. You're only using alerts? woah.

Comment: Consider using jQuery - it's easier to work with, easier to write, and more cross-platform. Look into the `$.get` method of jQuery and your life will be so much easier.

Or it could just be that ugly double quote @FabrícioMatté pointed out...

Comment: I always suggest learning the underlying language before adding in libraries like jQuery. Then you'll actually know why something doesn't work cross browser out of the box, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL contains syntax error
Pls change it to   :        myxml.open("GET","/suggest?query=str",true);

I have added a tutorial link which suits your requirement:

http://www.java4s.com/ajax/checking-user-name-availability-with-ajax-google-style/